# How to write a handlebars helpers to return the day of week?

Tags: handlebars.js, momentjs

How to write a handlebars helpers to return the day of week? looks the return result not changed by 'planDate', always shows today's value.

html handlebars template

```
         <tr>
            <td>{{formatTime 'planDate'}} {{planDate}}</td>
        </tr>
```

js:

```
      Handlebars.registerHelper("formatTime", function(v) {
                var x = v.value;
                return moment(x).format("dddd");    
            });
```

[image]

Comment: Your code seems to be missing pieces. What is `v` in the `formatTime` helper. Why does the template call `format` and not `formatTime`? And why are you passing the string `'planDate'` to your formatting helper?

Comment: Thank you for reminding, already updated. Cause I tested many ways and copied wrong code...the result shows as picture showed, only showed todays value.

Comment: What does `v.value` evaluate to?

Comment: The JS file code shows Handlebars.registerHelper, I think v.value should be the {{planDate}} value in html. and the value is fetched from database.

Comment: When you wrap quotes around your argument to your helper, as you are doing in `{{formatTime 'planDate'}}`, you are making your argument a String - in this case, a String that evaluates to `planDate`. As Strings in JavaScript do not have a `value` property by default, when you assign `v.value` to `x`, you are assigning to `x` the value of `undefined`. As you are passing `undefined` to your `moment` constructor, it defaults to the current date.

Comment: Thank you, May I know how to fix it? cause I thought if I want to use formatTime it should be write like this {{formatTime 'planDate'}}, the first time to use handlebars and moment js really not sure how to use them together...

Comment: Assuming you have a `planDate` object which is a valid JS Date, you would update your template to `{{formatTime planDate}}` and your helper to `return moment(v).format("dddd");` and removing the `var x = v.value;` bit. (I would also suggest renaming the `v` parameter as "v" is not a good variable name.)

Comment: It works. Really got a lot, thank you again!